# Radix Sort Convert Ascending to Descending (Pascal)

Tags: pascal, freepascal, turbo-pascal

***edit**

I have radix sort procedure, and i got this code on another site referension. But this radix sort only for ascending not for descending.

Can you guys help me how to make it to descending

```
Program SortStuff;

Uses Crt, Dos;

Type
    AType = Array [1..400] of Integer;
    Ptr   = ^Node;
    Node  = Record
          Info : Integer;
          Link : Ptr;
        end;
    LType = Array [0..9] of Ptr;

Var
   Ran     : AType;
   MaxData : Integer;
```

and this section of the procedure of refill

```
Procedure Refill (Var A : AType; Var L : LType);
Var
  I, J : Integer;
  P    : Ptr;
begin
  J := 1;
  For I := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    P := L [I];
    While P <> Nil do
    begin
      A [J] := P^.Info;
      P := P^.Link;
      J := J + 1;
    end;
  end;
  For I := 0 to 9 do
    L [I] := Nil;
end;
```

This is the radix sort code

```
Procedure RadixSort (Var A : AType; MaxData : Integer);
Var
  L        : LType;
  I,
  divisor,
  ListNo,
  Number   : Integer;
begin
  For I := 0 to 9 do L [I] := Nil;
  divisor := 1;
  While divisor <= 1000 do
  begin
    I := 1;
    While I <= MaxData do
    begin
      Number := A [I];
      ListNo := Number div divisor MOD 10;
      Insert (L, Number, ListNo);
      I := I + 1;
    end;
    Refill (A, L);
    divisor := 10 * divisor;
  end;
end;
```

and this the main code

```
begin
    ReadData (Ran, MaxData);
    Writeln ('Unsorted : ');
    WriteArray (Ran, MaxData);
    RadixSort (Ran, MaxData);
    Writeln ('Sorted   : ');
    WriteArray (Ran, MaxData);
    readln;
end.
```

this is the result of the compiler when ascending

```
Unsorted :
 7131 5110  638 7836 3809 1278 9577 7590 8244 5902 7610 4787 6809 1510 3564 3358 6411  995 4966 9800 5807  678 9174 9385 4146 1824 4869 9383 3638 2304 8130 1178 5102 2192 1739 1643 2965 7245 7050 2416 3778 5515 4395 3418 4869 9814 6073 5014 8501  210 3966 4891 8992 2882 5512 3775  799 9985 8189 4664 4360  241 7681 6235 7152 8032 8874   19 9253 1943 2049 8301 1848 9175 8698 6578 8111 4442 5157 8832 9848 6448 3881 2753 4100 1130 9516 4539 5515 9756 1047 3313 2937  575 8634 9439 8508    8 2596 3814 4996 5129 9810 1220 8242 7672 7342 1320 3195 7590 4342 5697 7866 2326 6726 3441 8276 6531 2211 6285 4492 9310 2155 2349 1396 9157  772 3984 1955 9417 7644 4814   90 7922  180 6536 7018 7411  263 3775 2014 2339 4064 6623 4173 4031 5979 4930 7654 4039 1531 4916 7357 8802 6935 6108 1580 3999 6225 2641 6330 6907 2584 3437 7753 8680 2192 4461  748  983  364 1695  197 8174 3128  104 4724  546 3826 7640 8669 4481 4763  599 2983 4433   92 8317 8102  413   91 1355 7456 4577 8442   26 8319 5010 1140 1232 1688 4080 4445 3548 5713 8391 4295  296  294 1477 8487 5823 9493 4528  434 2589 9499 6092 9784 6773 1907 9382 2203 3774 8438 8672 3290 3590 4540 2912 7308 9782 5615 8352 9456 5867 5657  218 6838 6294 3295 4741 5949 9369 8949 9672 5853 7054  855 3755 3113 4712 9043 3412 4546 2567 9934 2034 2007 1845 6466 2815 3012  498 5736 2487  881 6250  780 6817 7309 8503 9697 6149 7132 6936 5692 2757 6150 2705 1401 9272 4190 6116 8096 2386 2027 8913 7734 7318 4423 8439 7087 7995 8429 7139  818 1495 3284 2418 3295 5121 2989 5741  433 1905 5468 9828 8946 3179 7615  894 9766 2971  847 6450 4686 9597 4851 2080 7062 1956 2386 7476 1703 2738 3864 6491 7545 3046 1432 1050 3534 6054 5005 4862 9126 2877 1259 8613 1209 4982  236 9877 1697 4142 7484 2562 1554 8105 6483 3440 1462 8463 2006 7193 8316  281 6544  645 7043 2857   70 5525 6953 8924 7032 7593 4514 2192 8088   59 2861 4685  897 7319 3300  410  773 2147 9992 2985 8834  302  437 4323 6566 8357 9802 8257 7543 3607 1131  564 9474 9203 9127  575  708 7767
Sorted   :
    8   19   26   59   70   90   91   92  104  180  197  210  218  236  241  263  281  294  296  302  364  410  413  433  434  437  498  546  564  575  575  599  638  645  678  708  748  772  773  780  799  818  847  855  881  894  897  983  995 1047 1050 1130 1131 1140 1178 1209 1220 1232 1259 1278 1320 1355 1396 1401 1432 1462 1477 1495 1510 1531 1554 1580 1643 1688 1695 1697 1703 1739 1824 1845 1848 1905 1907 1943 1955 1956 2006 2007 2014 2027 2034 2049 2080 2147 2155 2192 2192 2192 2203 2211 2304 2326 2339 2349 2386 2386 2416 2418 2487 2562 2567 2584 2589 2596 2641 2705 2738 2753 2757 2815 2857 2861 2877 2882 2912 2937 2965 2971 2983 2985 2989 3012 3046 3113 3128 3179 3195 3284 3290 3295 3295 3300 3313 3358 3412 3418 3437 3440 3441 3534 3548 3564 3590 3607 3638 3755 3774 3775 3775 3778 3809 3814 3826 3864 3881 3966 3984 3999 4031 4039 4064 4080 4100 4142 4146 4173 4190 4295 4323 4342 4360 4395 4423 4433 4442 4445 4461 4481 4492 4514 4528 4539 4540 4546 4577 4664 4685 4686 4712 4724 4741 4763 4787 4814 4851 4862 4869 4869 4891 4916 4930 4966 4982 4996 5005 5010 5014 5102 5110 5121 5129 5157 5468 5512 5515 5515 5525 5615 5657 5692 5697 5713 5736 5741 5807 5823 5853 5867 5902 5949 5979 6054 6073 6092 6108 6116 6149 6150 6225 6235 6250 6285 6294 6330 6411 6448 6450 6466 6483 6491 6531 6536 6544 6566 6578 6623 6726 6773 6809 6817 6838 6907 6935 6936 6953 7018 7032 7043 7050 7054 7062 7087 7131 7132 7139 7152 7193 7245 7308 7309 7318 7319 7342 7357 7411 7456 7476 7484 7543 7545 7590 7590 7593 7610 7615 7640 7644 7654 7672 7681 7734 7753 7767 7836 7866 7922 7995 8032 8088 8096 8102 8105 8111 8130 8174 8189 8242 8244 8257 8276 8301 8316 8317 8319 8352 8357 8391 8429 8438 8439 8442 8463 8487 8501 8503 8508 8613 8634 8669 8672 8680 8698 8802 8832 8834 8874 8913 8924 8946 8949 8992 9043 9126 9127 9157 9174 9175 9203 9253 9272 9310 9369 9382 9383 9385 9417 9439 9456 9474 9493 9499 9516 9577 9597 9672 9697 9756 9766 9782 9784 9800 9802 9810 9814 9828 9848 9877 9934 9985 9992
```

then i tried to modify `ListNo := Number div divisor MOD 10;` and reverse it into `ListNo := divisor div Number MOD 10;` and the final result become to

```
Unsorted :
 7131 5110  638 7836 3809 1278 9577 7590 8244 5902 7610 4787 6809 1510 3564 3358 6411  995 4966 9800 5807  678 9174 9385 4146 1824 4869 9383 3638 2304 8130 1178 5102 2192 1739 1643 2965 7245 7050 2416 3778 5515 4395 3418 4869 9814 6073 5014 8501  210 3966 4891 8992 2882 5512 3775  799 9985 8189 4664 4360  241 7681 6235 7152 8032 8874   19 9253 1943 2049 8301 1848 9175 8698 6578 8111 4442 5157 8832 9848 6448 3881 2753 4100 1130 9516 4539 5515 9756 1047 3313 2937  575 8634 9439 8508    8 2596 3814 4996 5129 9810 1220 8242 7672 7342 1320 3195 7590 4342 5697 7866 2326 6726 3441 8276 6531 2211 6285 4492 9310 2155 2349 1396 9157  772 3984 1955 9417 7644 4814   90 7922  180 6536 7018 7411  263 3775 2014 2339 4064 6623 4173 4031 5979 4930 7654 4039 1531 4916 7357 8802 6935 6108 1580 3999 6225 2641 6330 6907 2584 3437 7753 8680 2192 4461  748  983  364 1695  197 8174 3128  104 4724  546 3826 7640 8669 4481 4763  599 2983 4433   92 8317 8102  413   91 1355 7456 4577 8442   26 8319 5010 1140 1232 1688 4080 4445 3548 5713 8391 4295  296  294 1477 8487 5823 9493 4528  434 2589 9499 6092 9784 6773 1907 9382 2203 3774 8438 8672 3290 3590 4540 2912 7308 9782 5615 8352 9456 5867 5657  218 6838 6294 3295 4741 5949 9369 8949 9672 5853 7054  855 3755 3113 4712 9043 3412 4546 2567 9934 2034 2007 1845 6466 2815 3012  498 5736 2487  881 6250  780 6817 7309 8503 9697 6149 7132 6936 5692 2757 6150 2705 1401 9272 4190 6116 8096 2386 2027 8913 7734 7318 4423 8439 7087 7995 8429 7139  818 1495 3284 2418 3295 5121 2989 5741  433 1905 5468 9828 8946 3179 7615  894 9766 2971  847 6450 4686 9597 4851 2080 7062 1956 2386 7476 1703 2738 3864 6491 7545 3046 1432 1050 3534 6054 5005 4862 9126 2877 1259 8613 1209 4982  236 9877 1697 4142 7484 2562 1554 8105 6483 3440 1462 8463 2006 7193 8316  281 6544  645 7043 2857   70 5525 6953 8924 7032 7593 4514 2192 8088   59 2861 4685  897 7319 3300  410  773 2147 9992 2985 8834  302  437 4323 6566 8357 9802 8257 7543 3607 1131  564 9474 9203 9127  575  708 7767
Sorted   :
 7131 5110 7836 3809 1278 9577 7590 8244 5902 7610 4787 6809 1510 3564 3358 6411 4966 9800 5807 9174 9385 4146 1824 4869 9383 3638 2304 8130 1178 5102 2192 1739 1643 2965 7245 7050 2416 3778 5515 4395 3418 4869 9814 6073 5014 8501 3966 4891 8992 2882 5512 3775 9985 8189 4664 4360 7681 6235 7152 8032 8874 9253 1943 2049 8301 1848 9175 8698 6578 8111 4442 5157 8832 9848 6448 3881 2753 4100 1130 9516 4539 5515 9756 1047 3313 2937 8634 9439 8508 2596 3814 4996 5129 9810 1220 8242 7672 7342 1320 3195 7590 4342 5697 7866 2326 6726 3441 8276 6531 2211 6285 4492 9310 2155 2349 1396 9157 3984 1955 9417 7644 4814 7922 6536 7018 7411 3775 2014 2339 4064 6623 4173 4031 5979 4930 7654 4039 1531 4916 7357 8802 6935 6108 1580 3999 6225 2641 6330 6907 2584 3437 7753 8680 2192 4461 1695 8174 3128 4724 3826 7640 8669 4481 4763 2983 4433 8317 8102 1355 7456 4577 8442 8319 5010 1140 1232 1688 4080 4445 3548 5713 8391 4295 1477 8487 5823 9493 4528 2589 9499 6092 9784 6773 1907 9382 2203 3774 8438 8672 3290 3590 4540 2912 7308 9782 5615 8352 9456 5867 5657 6838 6294 3295 4741 5949 9369 8949 9672 5853 7054 3755 3113 4712 9043 3412 4546 2567 9934 2034 2007 1845 6466 2815 3012 5736 2487 6250 6817 7309 8503 9697 6149 7132 6936 5692 2757 6150 2705 1401 9272 4190 6116 8096 2386 2027 8913 7734 7318 4423 8439 7087 7995 8429 7139 1495 3284 2418 3295 5121 2989 5741 1905 5468 9828 8946 3179 7615 9766 2971 6450 4686 9597 4851 2080 7062 1956 2386 7476 1703 2738 3864 6491 7545 3046 1432 1050 3534 6054 5005 4862 9126 2877 1259 8613 1209 4982 9877 1697 4142 7484 2562 1554 8105 6483 3440 1462 8463 2006 7193 8316 6544 7043 2857 5525 6953 8924 7032 7593 4514 2192 8088 2861 4685 7319 3300 2147 9992 2985 8834 4323 6566 8357 9802 8257 7543 3607 1131 9474 9203 9127 7767   92   91  638  995  678  799  575  772  748  983  546  599  855  881  780  818  894  847  645  897  773  564  575  708   90  364  413  434  498  433  410  437   19  263  296  294  281  302  210  241  218  236   70  180  197    8   59   26  104
```

Comment: To get descending, your `Refill`, which you don't show, should copy the sections in reverse order. You could also flip the array that was sorted ascending.

Comment: well i tried reversing the array, but it caused failure

Comment: Show what you did - perhaps we can help.

Comment: To be honest and direct, I find it quite lazy of you to copy a piece of software from a [site](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/SORTING/0023.PAS.html), and then *post it verbatim* here with a request of modifying it to suite your needs. It doesn't show any engagement of yourself. If this is a homework assignment, how do you think you will ever learn something, if you ask other people to do your homework.

Comment: well, i tried to modiy the code. but i don't know how to do it properly. I tried to modify `ListNo := Number div divisor MOD 10;` and reverse that to this `ListNo := divisor div Number MOD 10;` and it almost work. but didn't convert full of descending

Comment: As a minimum then, show **in your question** what exactly you did to solve your problem, why you thought it would solve the problem, and why it did not work.

Comment: already edit the post you can see the problem there

Comment: You can not just throw in whatever first comes to mind. Your modification makes no sense. In order for you to be able to modify the code you MUST understand it. There really is no way around it, you MUST understand it. So I leave it for you to investigate how the current code works. After you understand it, it will be obvious how you can modify it. I will check back tomorrow to lend you a hand if you need help with figuring out the present code.